# Unable to redirect after submitting login credentials on hosting site but able to do it on localhost

Tags: php, authentication, web-hosting

```
    <?php
session_start();
include('head1.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])!="") {
header("Location: index.php");
exit();

}

//check if form is submitted
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','rating_system');
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
$query="select * from tbl_users where email ='$email' and 
password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    header("Location:afterlogin.php");
} else {
    $errormsg = "Incorrect Email or Password!!!";
}
}
```

This code works well at localhost but not on the hosting website where the site is live..
i have to manually enter the afterlogin.php in browser to get to that page

Comment: Your local host probably has output caching on

Comment: add`ob_start();` at the to of your php code

Comment: Most likely you spit out some data to the client which results in the `header()` not actually getting sent. You can easily find out by examining the result you receive in your browsers console.

Comment: @dean your solution worked...Thanks

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['user_id'])!=""` is invalid code. Should be `isset($_SESSION['user_id'])` or `$_SESSION['user_id'] !=""`